# Are distributions of position and momentum assumed to be independent in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

Given a wave-function of a single particle we can calculate probability density for positions. We can also calculate probability density for momenta. Are these probability densities assumed to be always independent?

Or, in other words, if we measure position and momentum of a particle (for example electron in hydrogen being in the ground state), should we expect that these two random quantities independent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To say that position and momentum are not independent random variables in QM really undersells the point. It is not that we cannot measure them independently, the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) states that we cannot measure both quantities simultaneously at all.

What this means is that the distribution of momentum depends not only on the *outcome* of a measurement of position, it depends on *whether we measured position at all*. We cannot measure momentum and then ask what we *would* have measured if we had also tried to measure position, because that would change the outcome of the momentum measurement.

Comment: Isn't it the case that the uncertainty principle just tells us that product of the dispersions of the two distributions (one for position and another for momentum) is always larger than a certain number? So, it does not tell anything about correlation (or any relation) between two distributions.

Comment: In a strict sense yes, but the term is also used more loosely to describe the fact that non-commutting observables cannot be simultaneously defined or measured

Comment: In terms of distributions, 2 quantities are independent if their join distribution can be written as $f(x, p) =f_1(x)f_2(p)$. In QM we cannot write down $f(x,p)$ *at all*. (At least not as a true probability distribution)

Comment: What I know, is that if a wave function is such that its position distribution is very narrow, it will have a momentum distribution that is very broad (and the other way around). However, by itself it does not mean that position and momentum cannot be measured at the same time.

Comment: Rigoursly the fact that there is no joint distribution for non-commutting observables follows from [Bell's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem)

Comment: Conceptually it is normally seen as a consequence of the uncertainty principle. The point of the uncertainty principle is not simply that there are 2 distributions with an inverse relationship, it is that reducing the uncertainty in one quantity (say by measuring it, setting its uncertainty to 0) will actually increase the uncertainty in the other distribution. It is not only the outcome, but the simply the act of measurement which has an effect.

Comment: You absolutely can measure position and momentum simultaneously. The issue is how accurately those measurements are.

Answer (score 2):

> if we measure position and momentum of a particle (for example electron in hydrogen being in the ground state), should we expect that these two random quantities independent?

No. The momentum probability distribution and the position probability distribution have an inverse relationship with each other, which is a direct consequence of the Heisenberg's uncertainty relation.
Suppose you have a certain *wave packet*. What is the special thing about a wave packet? Well, it's confined to a certain region of space. Let's say that it is confined within a length $a$. So, you know that the particle can not exist outside of that region of space, and so the uncertainty principle puts you into a position where you can not measure the momentum arbitrarily accurately. This is why, its probability distribution is also dependent upon that of the position. Mathematically speaking, the momentum and position wavefunctions are related by a fourier transform-
$$\psi(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Psi(p)\text{e}^{ipx/\hbar}\ dp$$
From this formula, we can see that the position probability density, which is $|\Psi(x)|^2$ is obviously dependent on the functional form of $\Psi(p)$. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes, I know that the shape of the position probability density determines the shape of the momentum probability density. In this particular sense these two densities are related (determined by each other). However, my question is specifically about dependency between the two distributions in the statistical sense. In more detail, I am asking if combined distribution of position and momentum can be represented as a product of the distributions for position and for momentum: d(x,p) = d1(x) * d2(p).

Comment: No. See, by probability theory, for dependent events, the formula is- $P(A \cap B)=P(A)*P(B|A)$. Since the outcome of momentum is dependent upon the outcome of position, and vice versa, you can not write $P(B)=P(B|A)$, and so they are dependent on each other

Comment: Yes, but the question is if these two events are dependent. If d1(x) is determined by d2(p) and d2(p) is determined by d1(x), it does not mean that d(x, p) = d1(x) * d2(p).

Comment: The fact that d2(p) can be obtained from d1(x) using Fourier transformation does not mean that outcome of position measurement depends on outcome of momentum measurement.

Comment: It seems to be like the answer should be yes- When you measure the momentum, it can come out as per the momentum probability distribution, but once you have measured it, the system comes into a pure state of momentum. So, in that case all the positions of the particle are equally likely. Which means the position you now get is independent of what you found out the momentum to be. The reverse can also be said to be true. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Any real world position measurement result also implicitly includes a momentum measurement. Why? Any measurement of x results in some psi(x), its Fourier transform is psi(p), both are measurement results and quantum states, they are simply represented in different bases and have inversely related widths, neither width can be zero. If the position measurement result is accurate (ie, psi(x) is narrow), the momentum measurement is commensurately not accurate (ie, psi(p) is wide). This is the stipulation of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, it distinctly does not say x and p cannot be measured simultaneously, it simply says the accuracies of the simultaneous x and p results are inversely related, and neither width can be zero, as the product of delta x and delta p must be greater than or equal to hbar/2. This product cannot be zero, so neither delta can be zero. Thus, ideal quantum pure states, and single real numbered eigenvalues, are not physically realizable by any means whether manmade or natural. So every physical realization of a position measurement is also a momentum measurement.

Re independence of x and p, a free particle at position x’ may have any value of p independent of x’, and a free particle with momentum value p’ may have any value of x independent of p’. So x and p may be considered independent, while their wave function widths (in their respective eigenvalue domain spaces) are inversely related, as any Fourier transform pairs.